# Pattern Recognition Puzzle - What would 100 correspond to?

Tags: pattern-recognition

There is a mathematical puzzle I saw this morning that I am having trouble with.

Seemed easy initially but couldn't crack the code. Can anybody please help work out the answer for the below?

Given the following pattern, find out 1) What is the mathematical formula used to derive the number of the right from the number on the left? 2) What number can be derived from 100 when applying the same formula?

2 => -1

3 => -2

6 => 3

8 => 3

14 => 6

16 => 9

20 => 14

22 => 13

37 => 26

40 => 35

48 => 38

50 => 45

51 => 43

56 => 48

58 => 48

60 => 55

61 => 53

91 => 82

100 => ?

101 => 88

Comment: the question after the edit is completely different lol

Comment: haha.. yeah first time using stackexchange, didn't notice that the line-breaks weren't working in the first post! Thanks for having a look at my little puzzle :-)

Comment: don't you have access to more values?

Comment: One more just came in - 37 => 26. It's actually an office "get-to-know each other" puzzle game. Each gets a pair of number, and we have to introduce ourselves to another one to get a new pair of number :)

Comment: but you are sure it has an actual pattern right?

Comment: I'm very sure, the puzzle provider gave us the assurance there is a formula used.

Comment: Trivial observation: $n-f(n)\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$

Comment: Not true with the 37 => 26 pair though.. got a new one from a colleague : 101 => 88

Comment: Can you add all of the pairs to the main post once you get all of them?

Comment: Yup will try to do that, updated with the latest pair.

Comment: $100$ maps to $90$.

It appears that the last digit of each number corresponds to what the next step is.

For example, we have $6$ and $8$ have a difference of $0$, and $56$ and $58$ have a difference of $0$. Similarly, $50$ to $51$ has the same difference as $60$ to $61$, which is $-2$. So, if $101$ is $88$, it must be that $100$ is $90$.

For fun, I gathered a few relations:

$0$ to $1$ is $-2$ ; $2$ to $3$ is $-2$ ; $6$ to $7$ is $-2$ ; $7$ to $8$ is $2$

Comment: Thanks for the observation Bonnaduck. I get that 0  to 1 is −2 ; 2 to 3 is −2 ; But how is it that 6 to 7 is −2  and 7 to 8 is 2  ?

Comment: There are an infinite number of functions which satisfy all the given values and produce different values for 100.

Comment: OK - but what would be one of these functions, user125261? :) Bonnaduck and Anonymous' responses converge to 90 being the answer. I will update this post once the office's resident puzzle-master reveals the function he has in mind.

Comment: @Chilaxis since 6 to 8 is 0, it must be that 6 to 7 is -(7 to 8). Since 7 to 0 is 9, and 8 to 0 is 7, we have 7 to 8 is 2, so 6 to 7 is -2.

Answer (score 4):

> I graphed it [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rxh7itp6f0). It seems pretty linear, and if you make a line of best fit, 100 would correspond to about 90. Although I can't seem to figure out the algorithm, hopefully the graph helps.

Comment: I don't think that looks pretty linear

Comment: Updated the link to show what I mean

Comment: Thanks for the attempt Anonymous! Looks like the answer could be a close call between 89 and 90.